# Bash script is not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I wanted to create a script that executes the `ls` command with the provided arguments. Why isn't it working?
I tried running it with for example `-R`, then it echoes (I echoed the same thing for comparison):

```
    ls "-R"
```

but says that it cannot access "-R":  no such file or directory. But when I execute `ls "-R"` in the terminal, it works.

The script itself:

```
text='ls'

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    text+=' "'
    text+=$1
    text+='"'

    shift

done
echo 'ls "-R"'

echo $text
$text
```

Comment: ls "$@" will run ls with all arguments in the positional parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrong quoting is the problem. `"` does not quote (and, which is the problem here, does not get removed!) if it is contained in a variable. Exception: `eval $text`

You should assign the parameters to an array and use `ls "${vars[@]}"` or `ls "$@"` instead.

Compare the two calls:

```
set -x
ls -l
ls "-l"
set +x
```

Comment: FYI, I added "eval" before "$text" and it's working! Thanks, man! And the one below, thanks too!

Answer (score 3):

That's not how quoting work in bash. When entering

```
ls "-R"
```

quotes removal happens on the command, so the command becomes

```
ls -R
```

If, on the other hand, if you set

```
text='ls "-R"'
```

and run `$text`, the quote removal does not happen. See `man bash` under EXPANSIONS:

> After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the characters \, ', and " that did not result from one of the above expansions are removed.

`"` here resulted from parameter expansion, so it is not removed.